# Easy and good book on combinatorial problems

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, reference-books, applied-mathematics, mathematics-in-daily-life, math-puzzle

I am searching for a book on combinatorics and/or mathematical puzzles for very beginners in easy English. The book should not contain detail mathematical expressions, will contain easy understanding logic behind the theory instead. I don't need problems/exercises and solutions as the book is not for mathematics student. I need the book for mathematics lovers who want to enjoy the theory maybe with some history and story. This should be a story book which one can read in leisure mood and can enjoy the thrill of mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

This book is unfortunately out of print, but it is still accessible: *The Penguin Book of Curious and Interesting Puzzles* by David Wells. A majority of the problems are of a discrete or combinatorial flavor, and he avoids getting into mathematics in the form of mathematics in the answer. In addition, the book essential doubles as a history of recreational puzzles which is the original reason I came across it.

Comment: Does this explain the Science/Mathematics behind the puzzles?

Comment: Yes when applicable. For example, the Bridges of Konigsberg problem is included and the explanation is roughly equivalent to what you would see in an introductory discrete math book.